# Definition of a treatment

Tags: meaning

I'm struggling to think of an appropriate name for these:

- Reflexology
- Deep tissue massage
- Acupuncture

And a corresponding appropriate name for these:

- Reflexology for 30 minutes
- Reflexology for 60 minutes
- Deep tissue massage for 45 minutes
- Deep tissue massage for 1 hour 30 minutes
- Acupuncture for 30 minutes

If the first group can be described as 'treatments' I wouldn't know what to call the second group, and vice versa.

Can anyone help?

**Edit 01/04/17 - Additional Part to Question**

If X is the collective name for the first set of bullet points, then so far I have asked for names for:

1. X
2. X + Duration

What about:

3. X + Duration **+ Specific Date/Time.**

Comment: Treatments and Variants of the treatments.

Comment: @Yosef, what would you give as an example of a 'treatment' then?

Comment: Normally elements of the second group would be called "sessions".

Answer (score 2):

**Treatments**

- Reflexology
- Deep tissue massage
- Acupuncture

**Treatment Sessions Offered**

- Reflexology, **30** minutes
- Reflexology, **60** minutes
- Deep tissue massage, **45** minutes
- Deep tissue massage, **90** minutes
- Acupuncture, **30** minutes

Comment: Thank you.  If the first set of bullet points are 'Treatments', then what would be an example of a 'Treatment Modality' (I'm taking the word 'modality' from the comment you originally made after my question)?

Comment: The modality is what happens within the treatment: Talk therapy or a massage. Also, you cannot charge for a general treatment of unspecified length, so the Sessions listing is where you display the charges: A, 30 minutes ($30); B, 45 minutes ($40).

Answer (score 2):

Typically, when a treatment procedure is given a time frame, it is known as a **session**.

*A 90-minute massage session.*

*I had a 50-minute session with my therapist.*

Alternatively, initial visits are called **evaluations.**

*"Yes, Mr. Smith, we'll start with a 90-minute evaluation, and then I'll lay out a treatment plan."*

Comment: Thanks. Based on your answer, Reflexology is an example of a 'Treatment Procedure' and Reflexology for 30 minutes is an example of a 'Session'. What's an example of a 'Treatment'?

Comment: I think semantics here with "treatment procedure" being redundant. If anything, *procedure* should be specific, but in alternative health seems rarely used, e.g. Swedish massage treatment [procedure would sound weird].

Answer (score 0):

you first three are not treatments, they're treatment methods or techniques.  treatments must actually treat, so to speak, so your other examples are treatments.  if we call the first three "treatments", it's just a convenience.

Comment: Thanks. So if 'Reflexology' is a 'Treatment Technique', and 'Reflexology for 30 minutes' is a 'Treatment', what name would you use for 'Reflexology for 30 minutes on 03/04/17 at 9am'?

Comment: "What treatment do you recommend?" - "Reflexology for 30 minutes, once a week."  "What was your most recent treatment?" -  "Reflexology for 30 minutes on 03/04/17 at 9am".